# Merge Flaticon collections / use multiple collections at the same time

Tags: css, svg, truetype

We are using [Flaticons](https://www.flaticon.com/) on our website (their **Iconfont** format). However I would like to add a few more icons into the pack. I tried creating another collection on Flaticon and then manually merge them but it would not work for me. Especially since I am just able to merge .css and .svg files manually.

The file structure looks like this:

[image]

However using 2 Flaticon packs at the same time seems to interfere with each other. I believe it's because of the unicode identifiers.

What is the way to use 2 Flaticon packs next to each other or merge them into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Flaticon does not offer any tool or way to do that. The only way is to change manually the file names and use them side by side.

The response I got in an email from Flaticon:

> We are sorry to inform you that the only way would be manually
>   changing the names of the inconfonts files one by one. You will need
>   to extract first the files in order to change the name manually:
>   [image]